# Gain key and iv from plaintext and ciphertext?

Tags: security, encryption

If somebody knows plainText(original text), cipherText(encrypted text) and algorithm name, can he/she gain Key and IV? If algorithms are different in this case assume AES encryption algorithm.

Comment: This is a [Known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) and AES is not susceptible to it.

Comment: @AlexK. useful link, thank you Alex.

Comment: Learning the key would be an attack and AES does not suffer from it. Learning the IV is usually not considered an attack since it's assumed to be public anyways. The IV is generally different for each message and sent alongside the message. For some modes of operation  it might possible to recover the IV when knowing a plaintext/ciphertext pair, for most modes it's not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.